# How can I create two independent windows in Python with opencv and tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I am planning a Python application with the following library:

- opencv
- tkinter
  (originally Pygame was planned but there are problems with Tkinter on MAC M1 (Monterey) )

What I want to realize is a Tkinter window as root app with the possibility to control an opencv window (with running video).
The two windows are already running (and yes - I am aware that imgshow blocks the root app with a waitkey).

I know that I can cancel the imgshow loop with a key - but my problem is that the opencv window closes (and the Tkinter root app gets the focus again).

Important is: I need the possibility that the opencv window (black screen) stays open (fullscreen on a second monitor).

The basic functionality is that I want to send commands from the Tkinter window to the opencv window.

I am not really a pro in Python - maybe someone can help me with some approaches or give me hints in a possible direction (threading, multiproccess ? ).

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: tkinter? make more windows using `Toplevel()` -- use threads, separate thread for opencv gui stuff, and pray it works, because opencv's GUI stuff isn't made to be thread-safe

Comment: Thanks Christoph - I know about Toplevel in Tkinter, but imgshow opens an own Window

Comment: if you aren't a pro, you'll have to become a pro, in tkinter and in opencv's GUI stuff. besides, this question isn't a simple programming question. its scope is huge.

Comment: The general hint is to keep your GUI thread with your UI stuff and the data thread with data stuff. I'm not sure what you wish to get in return to this question, since [so] isn't a code writing service and we cant see your code to give practical ideas. A [mre] helps to help you. Please take a look at [ask]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am aware of the respective GUI possibilities of the two libraries and how I should address them regarding reactivity. What I need is an approach to connect the two windows (without the Tkinter window losing usability). One of the ways to become a Pro is to ask for help even as a non-Pro. Please excuse me if I am not at the Pro level to ask questions here.....

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As I understand it, it should be solved via threading ? But isn't it also with threading that one thread only runs again when the other one pauses ? By the way, I don't expect any code ;) just approaches or keywords under which I can inform myself.

Comment: you have basic misconceptions about threading. please read introductions to threading.

Comment: @Ivo *But isn't it also with threading that one thread only runs again when the other one pauses ?* Yes, in Python a thread works in the time where other threads doing nothing through the GIL. But you will still be able to do more work with threads, think of it as effecientcy gain. There are really many ways of doing this. You may use threading and Queue or subprocess and pipes to communicate between programms or threads. Of course there can be more options but it depends what you need and what you feel comfterable with.

Comment: @Thingamabobs - many Thanks - A very helpful tip. I already had a look yesterday about threads and processes, queue and pools and I think I know now a bit more where the direction goes ;)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.